# How to stop SSH X11 forwarding when using vim?

Tags: vim, ssh, x11

When I launch vim on command line via SSH connection with X11 forwarding (eg. `ssh -X` or set ssh_config `X11Forwarding yes`), XQuartz.app is also launched. It takes a bit of time, so I cannot edit file quickly.
How to stop vim's X11 forwarding?

My computer: macOS Catalina
Remote computer: Linux / VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try the following command,

```
vim -X
```

`-X` means don't connect to the X server